# Hosting WCF service as AZURE app service VS2019

Tags: .net, wcf, azure-web-app-service

I am facing the issue while trying to deploy the WCF service (.Net framework 4.7) using VS2019 to Azure Web App. I am not able to access the service in browser. here is the [link](https://wcfservicedemo20191121055716.azurewebsites.net/IService1.svc).

I have already set CORS to * in Azure App Service.

Below is the service configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

**Service Contract**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between hosting the service in the local IIS server and in Azure App Service.
From your link, I found that you try to access the `https://baseaddress/IService1.svc`

> https://wcfservicedemo20191121055716.azurewebsites.net/IService1.svc

It is illegal. A default WCF project only contains Service.svc file, which includes a definition markup of service factory. It is a part of the WCF base address.
Therefore, in order to access the start page/WSDL, we should use the name of the service factory file.

> https://baseaddress/Service.svc

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.